# How to display websites in iframe

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sinatra

I am using ruby and sinatra.
I need to create a website that allows the user to upload a zipfile of other websites and display all of them in multiple iframes on the page but I'm not sure how to even start this.

so far I have made the website that can upload a zipfile and have placed it in an uploads folder and i can display that on website by doing

```
<iframe src="../uploads/test.html" width="100%" height="600">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

post '/upload' do
File.open('uploads/' + params['file'][:filename], 'w') do |f|
  f.write(params['file'][:tempfile].read)
end
end
```

the thing is i wont necessarily know the names of the html files or how many there are to just place the name of it

Comment: This code makes your code extremely hackable. Anyone can edit any file on the system by passing a malicious path. Anyway, you can use a gem like rubyzip to extract the file and move it to a designated place, keeping track of the filenames. Note that on Heroku you won't be able to create files anywhere other than the tmp/ directory. You could use a cloud storage provider as a workaround though.

Comment: how do i secure it?

Comment: don't allow user input for the path you write to.