# display page in iframe

Tags: ruby, sinatra

```
post '/uploadZIP' do
zipFile = params['zip'][:filename]
if zipFile.end_with? '.zip'
  File.open(params['zip'][:filename], 'w') do |f|
    f.write(params['zip'][:tempfile].read)
  end
extract_zip(zipFile, '..\VotersBest\public')
$websites = get_websites()
redirect to('/loginTA')

  end
end


#STORE WEBSITES IN ARRAY
def get_websites()
$directory = "public"
if Dir.exist? $directory
  siteArray = Array.new
  # go to pwd/dir
  Dir.chdir($directory) { siteArray = Dir.glob("*").select {|x| Dir.exist? x }}
# go back to parent dir
  siteArray
 end
end

get '/websites' do
 @instance_websites = $websites
 @website_url = $directory+ "/"+ @instance_websites[0] + "/index.html"
 erb :websites
end
```

it says sinatra doesnt know this ditty and i know thas because i dont have a get request but is there anyway to get around that? I have websites in different folders and I dont want to make a get request for each folder path
the line

@website_url = $directory+ "/"+ @instance_websites[0] + "/index.html"

gets the error

it says to try

```
get '/public/student1/index.html' do
"Hello World"
end
```

but there could be time where the folder isnt called "student"

Comment: you never define `$websites`. Also, you posted [a question with the same title recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47612817/how-to-display-websites-in-iframe) that has no answers. I advise you try and include more information in your question through edits.

Comment: sorry, its initialized though

Comment: try inspecting your `@instance_websites` variable. You make sure that `public/` is _not_ in the path. You can store the files in public, but don't include it in the path when you load them.

Comment: I have it the folders with the index.html in them
I now have @website_url = (@websites[0] + "/index.html")
which is /student1/index.html but i get 404 error